# FIPS Compliance in Java deployments

Tags: java, security, jetty, fips

I'm currently working as a QA engineer with a developer on a particular project which we're looking to deploy a FIPS compliant version of the app.

We currently have a standard deployment working without FIPS mode enabled.  However, when we've been trying to modify the SSL/TLS ciphers which our app is serving out we're pulling the same list of available ciphers.

```
Starting Nmap 7.25BETA1 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-20 10:36 EST
Host is up (0.011s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9443/tcp open  tungsten-https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp160k1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp160k1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp160k1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 1024) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp160k1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 1024) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings: 
|       Key exchange parameters of lower strength than certificate key
|_  least strength: A
```

I'm unsure where we can check to see whether or not FIPS mode is enabled or not.  Our app is currently using Java/Jetty as our web server.  I apologize if I didn't explain this very well.  But any advice/literature on how to enable FIPS in this type of deployment would be much appreciated.  I'm much more familiar with how this works in a Tomcat webserver.. I'm currently at a dead end with this type of web server.

Thanks

Comment: I would think for FIPS compliance you should be modifying the JVM's `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.properties`, so that it applies to all use of encryption, not specifically Jetty.